# Need to convert video URL from gallery into NSData (H.264) (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am selecting video from `UIImagePicker` and need to convert the videoUrl into NSData. Any ideas how to do this?

This is how I get my videoURL in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` for `UIImagePickerController`

```
let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
```

Answer (score 4):

Find this solution:

```
if let url = fileUrl {    
  do {
       let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
     } catch let error {
       print(error)
     }
}
```